# Spork, Vagrant, and Rspec

Tags: rspec, tdd, vagrant, spork

So, I'm working in a pretty complex development enviornment that is hard to replicate locally on my Mac, so we're using Vagrant boxes and Chef scripts to keep everyone on the same page. What I would like to do, is be able to run my RSpec tests locally (on the Mac), but have them connect to the DRb server (spork) running on the Vagrant box. In my Vagrantfile, I've done the following to forward the Spork port to the Mac host:
`config.vm.forward_port 8989, 8989`.

I ssh into the Vagrant box, and get the Spork server up an running, then I try to run my tests locally (Mac), and I'm told there's no DRb server running. Well, sure, not locally, but can't it just forward to the 8989 port to run it on the Vagrant box? Anyone have any idea how I can trick it to do so?

Oh, and my `.rspec` looks like this:

```
--color
--format documentation
--backtrace
--drb
```

Comment: Sure can. Are you sure your `Drb` server is running and bound to port 8989. Can you `vagrant ssh` and `wget https://localhost:8989`?