# Run rspec against vagrant box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, spork, gitlab

I want to run the rspec tests for Gitlab within vim (calling: !rspec). The problem is, i'm using the vagrant box provided here: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-vagrant-vm

This means that the whole app is running inside of the vagrant box, and when i call rspec from within vim, it tries to run locally.

Is there any way i can forward the rspec call to the vagrant box, and get the output back locally?

I've found this one: https://github.com/clintoncwolfe/vagrant-rspec-ci But its not what im looking for, since i have to run a custom command.

Maybe its related to: [Spork, Vagrant, and Rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428257/spork-vagrant-and-rspec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute any command over ssh, and return the output:

```
$ ssh user@host echo "hi"
hi
```

You could use this to run rspec:

```
$ ssh user@vagrant-ip "cd /path/to/project && rspec"
```

The thing to bear in mind with this approach is that your shell's environment must be set up correctly to allow access to the `rspec` command. Your mileage will vary depending on how you manage your rubies.

But you can set up a command in vim to execute this SSH command, and the output will be returned, e.g.:

```
:command VRspec exec "system('ssh user@vagrant-ip...')"
```